# Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "pedido"

Tags: xml, xsd

> Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "pedido". [7]
> Attribute "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" must be declared for element type "pedido". [7]
> cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'NOV-2-00003' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '^(NOV|TEM|PRO)-[0-5]-\d{5}$' for type 'codigoPedidoType'. [7]
> cvc-attribute.3: The value 'NOV-2-00003' of attribute 'codigo' on element 'pedido' is not valid with respect to its type, 'codigoPedidoType'. [7]
> XML validation finished.

I get these errors, but I've already tried everything. I don't get where is the issue. I've asked to ask IA to see if it can help, but it doesn't. I believe someone with good knowledge could see the problem.

### XML CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE pedido SYSTEM "pedido_A.dtd">


<pedido xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="pedido_B.xsd"
        codigo="NOV-2-00003">
    <cliente>  
        <nombre_completo>Paco López</nombre_completo>  
        <usuario>paco23</usuario>
        <telefono>950202020</telefono>  
    </cliente>  
    <producto stock="no">  
        <cantidad>1</cantidad>  
        <descripcion>camiseta</descripcion>  
        <precio_unitario moneda="euros">15</precio_unitario>  
    </producto>  
    <envio>  
        <nombre_contacto>Paco López</nombre_contacto>  
        <ubicacion>  
            <via>Plaza Constitución, 5</via>  
            <poblacion codigo_postal="04001">Almería</poblacion>  
        </ubicacion>  
    </envio>  
</pedido>
```

### XSD CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">


  <xs:element name="pedido">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="cliente" type="clienteType"/>
        <xs:element name="producto" type="productoType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="envio" type="envioType" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="codigo" type="codigoPedidoType" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="unique-codigo">
      <xs:selector xpath="."/>
      <xs:field xpath="@codigo"/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="clienteType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="nombre_completo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="razon_social" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="usuario" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="telefono" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="email" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="contrato" use="optional">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="sin_contrato"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="básico"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="plus"/>
          <xs:enumeration value="premium"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="productoType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="cantidad" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:element name="descripcion" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="precio_unitario" type="precioUnitarioType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="stock" type="xs:string" use="optional" default="sí"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="precioUnitarioType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:attribute name="moneda" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="euros"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="envioType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="nombre_contacto" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="ubicacion" type="ubicacionType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="ubicacionType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="via" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="poblacion" type="poblacionType"/>
      <xs:element name="provincia" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="poblacionType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="codigo_postal" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  
  <xs:simpleType name="codigoPedidoType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="^(NOV|TEM|PRO)-[0-5]-\d{5}$"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that error. However, your xs:pattern for codigoPedidoType should not have the `^` or `$` . Remove those and try re-validating.

Answer (score 1):

Two separate errors here.

> Attribute "xmlns:xsi" must be declared for element type "pedido". [7]
> Attribute "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" must be declared for element
> type "pedido". [7]

This appears to come from DTD-based validation. It seems you are doing both DTD-based and XSD-based validation. That seems unnecessary. However, if you're going to do it, then as far as DTDs are concerned `xmlns:xsi` and `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` are ordinary attributes and can't be used unless the DTD is written to allow them.

> cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'NOV-2-00003' is not facet-valid with respect
> to pattern '^(NOV|TEM|PRO)-[0-5]-\d{5}$' for type 'codigoPedidoType'.
> [7] cvc-attribute.3: The value 'NOV-2-00003' of attribute 'codigo' on
> element 'pedido' is not valid with respect to its type,
> 'codigoPedidoType'.

That error comes from the XSD processor, and it's because `$` and `^` have no special meaning in the XSD regex dialect; they are ordinary characters that represent themselves. Remove them from your pattern and all should be well.

Comment: Thanks Michael, it validates 

Comment: The SO way to indicate that an answer worked is to check the tick-mark that appears next to the answer, to mark it as accepted.